# laravel 5.8 routes not working in xampp after update?

Tags: laravel-5

i have a pc and desktop, they both used to have xampp and laravel 5.7, recently i updated laravel to 5.8 in my desktop and reset laptop and install laravel 5.8,, routes are working all fine in desktop laravel version ,, but in newly installed laravel in laptop they aren't working, i get 404 error except '/' i tried override all, ifmodule solution they are all fine it is not working in newly installed laravel 5.8 please help ...

PS : i also created seprate project in desktop and laptop ,, not copy paste but individually created in both of them..

i checked apache hhtp.config for ifmodule  and overrride and htaccess is default i haven't modified any and is same as all them in solution

i want to be able to use routes without using php artisan serve

Comment: could be anything. Check your apache version and the correct `.htaccess` as seen here https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: i changed htaccess as instructed it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of the Directory section in the vhost settings of xampp.